# how to save dictionary to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have a user management system and I want to save user info like coins, stats and more
my idea was to do a dictionary with keys like coin and stats and then send it to the SQL and to get it when I need it

I don't want to save it locally because then the user can change the values

I am using unity engine with PHP and SQL on the web

How can I save the dictionary in the database?

Comment: Serialize and store into TEXT column.

Comment: e.g. you could serialise to JSON format

Comment: Does it have to be stored on an eternal web/database server? What if you could serialise to JSON, then encrypt that? And when needed, load from local store, decrypt the data, then deserialise the unencrypted JSON?

Comment: If the dictionary has a static structure (you know the list of possible fields), then create a table (or tables) with corresponding columns and store the data there (2nd duplicate). If the structure is dynamic, like in case of an online shop's product properties, then use the first duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on from unity send data in array format to PHP or you can send the dictionary format to PHP. If you send dictionary format, I assume this as JSON format then in PHP use:

From unity send data in the format of:

`json_data = { id: 9899, coins: 100, stats: "somevalue"}`

In PHP:

```
<?php
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
?>
```

Insert data to SQL:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user_stat(u_id,coins,stats) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
```

When you will read data from PHP to unity if you want to read in same format then PHP will read data from SQL in array format then you have to encode array into json using json_encode() function and send back to unity.

I hope it will work. If it helps you then don't forget to accept and upvote :).